# How to add submission successful to php upon submission?

Tags: php, sql, forms, pdo

I need to add a success message after my html form is submitted. I've tried a few examples I've found online and even tried to write my own, but they either do not work or keep the form from submitting. I'm still really new to PHP, so any help is appreciated. I'm not too picky on how the message appears, just as long as it is there. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new pdo('sqlsrv:Server=xxxx,1433;database=xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tsql = "INSERT INTO testtable (date, position, referral) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($tsql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $_REQUEST['date'],
        $_REQUEST['position'],
        $_REQUEST['referral']
    ));

    /* The following call to closeCursor() may be required by some drivers */
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    // and now we're done; close it
    $dbh = null;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("PDO Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `echo "Success!"` after the `$dbh = null;` line.

If an error (exception) occurs between try {} and catch (). It will be caught by the catch() lines, which will cause one of the `die()'s` to be displayed. If you reach the `$dbh = null` line, your query was successfull.

Comment: I tried that, but I was putting it in the wrong spot I guess. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it helped (click the check mark left of the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session variable then retrieve and clear it in your view file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether your HTML form is submitted or not by writing a piece of code like this one.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "Form Submitted";
    } 
?>
```

And HTML form like this :

```
<form >
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>    
</form>
```

it is just an example for you to set as u want.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax-example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ajax form simple example</h1>
<form id="foo">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
```

Javascript (ajax-example.js):

```
// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
            error: function(){
               alert('error');
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
               //here you can put do thing cool like a $('element').html('loading-image.gif')
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('.message').html('success!! '+data);
            }
    });
});
```

PHP (form.php)

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new pdo('sqlsrv:Server=xxxx,1433;database=xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tsql = "INSERT INTO testtable (date, position, referral) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($tsql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $_REQUEST['date'],
        $_REQUEST['position'],
        $_REQUEST['referral']
    ));

    /* The following call to closeCursor() may be required by some drivers */
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    // and now we're done; close it
    $dbh = null;

   return 'PUT SOMETHING HERE IF YOU WANT';
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("PDO Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

For more information search for `jquery ajax submit`